# BrowserState history & thin pages in search

Tags: web-crawler, history.js, browser-state

I'm looking for some opinions on the best way to implement BrowserState history.

Current situation, my eCommerce site is currently driven using hash in the url. Whenever a user changes the results, the page will add some hash values to the url and reload the results. For example:

```
/products/ 
click button -> /products/#button=1
click sort -> /products/#button=1&sort=4
click category -> /products/#button=1&sort=4&cat=2
click pagination -> /products/#button=1&sort=4&cat=2&page=2
```

If a user shares this link, the correct results will show up as the results displayed. However currently my canonical tag will point the search engine to /products/ and therefore missing out on lots of products being crawled from the page.

There are two options I see to get these crawled correctly:

1. Using Ajax Crawling - https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

(e.g. /products/!#button=1&sort=4&cat=2&page=2)

Advantages: - product urls do get crawled.
Disadvantages: - page titles, meta descriptions & content would be duplicates. Would this cause issues with thin pages with duplicate content being crawled?

1. BrowserState History - https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

The options that I consider using is history, as it supports all browser versions.
(e.g. /products/button_1/sort_4/cat_2/page_2/)

Advantages: products get crawled, unique content could be created for each page, clear url structure
Disadvantages: thin pages?

Any feedback on the ideas above would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance